# Cannot remove JLabel (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel

(sorry for my english) When I add JLabel to Form in Netbeans, I couldn´t move with it.I removed it from form. Now I want compile project and it show error message:

```
error: cannot find symbol jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
```

other jLabels are ok, but this one is wrong. i remove it from form, but it is always in inspector.

check printscreens (1. jLabel8 is wrong, i cant remove it; 2.other labels are ok, in menu is option to delete) :

**Screen1:**

[image]

**Screen2:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) to hard to help you with `Java Desktop Aplications`, because this Framework based on Swing methods is long time depreciated and un_suported, these areas were supported on [NetBeans Forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/), but looks like as these forums are long time died too,

2) use Standard [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), by using [Standard LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and listening for events by [Standard Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) rather that use Java Desktop Aplications Framework

3) for better help sooner please post here question that contains [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) examples for [SSCCE](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20sscce),

EDIT

4) in some cases isn't possible directly override basic Swing methods by using this Framework, f.e. starting with to change Java Cup Icon for FrameView

Answer (score 1):

Open the `.form` file corresponding to your frame (you'll find it in `<your_netbeans_projects_directory/<your_project>/src`).

It's an XML file, there you can delete reference to `jLabel8`. But I don't recommend to do that if you feel it's to tricky/risky.

A safer solution you can try is deleting the parent component of `jLabel8` and create it again.