# Form Loaded With Errors - Error in loading component property

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I work on java project in netbeans, and without reason when I try to open the designer of a java file, I got this error :

> Warning - Form Loaded With Errors
>
> Error in loading component property : [JPanel]->jPanel23->jToolBar2->
>   No such property exists in the component.
>
> Error in loading component property : [JPanel]->jPanel23->jToolBar2->
>   No such property exists in the component.
>
> Error in loading component property : [JPanel]->jPanel23->jToolBar2->
>   No such property exists in the component.
>
> Errors occured in loading the form data. It is not recommended to use
>   this form now in editable mode - data that could not be loaded would
>   be loast after saving the form.
>  Please go through the reported errors,
>   try to fix them if possible, and open the form again.
>  If you choose to
>   open the form as View Only you may see which beans are missing.

And here is the Exceptions errors :

```
org.netbeans.modules.form.PersistenceException: Unknown property
```

I work with NetBeans 7.4 and I can't update the software.

Is anyone know why I got this popup and maybe point me to a workaround ?

Thank you in advance.

Etix.

Comment: 1- Do a clean and build of the project; 2- Delete the cache and repeat step 1;

Comment: A similar question as been asked before, can you try it?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8870182/1140748

Comment: alain.janinm : I try and it seems to not working, and anyway I can't delete the component like this, it's risky (company software).

Comment: MadProgrammer : I just try but it doesn't work ...

Comment: @Etix Ok then can you try this, edit the form file and change the xml version in the header from 1.1 to 1.0 (related to known bug : https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=214294)

Comment: @alain.janinm I tried this already, but the XML has already 1.0 version

Comment: Ok... Can you provide the full stack trace (from ide logs) please?

Comment: Here is the end of IDE Log : https://ghostbin.com/paste/fnznr But I don't think there are important things about the problem

Comment: It will be hard to tell... Maybe you have done some refractoring that have corrupted your .form files. Please make sure that everything is valid. Other reason would be code issue, maybe your trying to load a component that rely on something that is not initialized. Finally, reading the log, I suspect your trying to serialize something that should not be serialized.

Comment: Hum... I see more or less. I will look in this way and come back here if I have news. Thanks for the informations and the help.